# windows 8 bind button to > and < mark

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am trying to rebind few buttons under windows 8.1 to get them working like they work under ubuntu.
I have [this](http://www.techsupportalert.com/files/images/pc_freeware/desktop_and_gui/ClickNType-500_1.png) layout on my laptop keyboard. I am trying to map , and . keys (1/2 buttons right from m) to < and > - just like they are seen on the picture (and on my keyboard). But no matter what I do, they do not work like that.

I tried using [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), but it does not seem to work. I tried:

```
!.::>
!,::<
```

To bind them to work with alt+. and alt+,

I left in

```
#z::Run www.autohotkey.com
```

And it works just fine, so I guess the program is working, i am just not using it correctly. When I  try to use bound , and . buttons then computer just plays system alert sound and does not do anything.

I also tried another program suggested in similar posts - it did not allow alt+key combinations to be bound at all. So what i am asking is- is it possible to achieve that using autohotkey and if yes, then how or - are there alternative ways to bind those 2 buttons to > and <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm the keys it will work for you.

```
!.::Send >
!,::Send <
```

Comment: worked like i charm. I just used SendInput instead of Send as the page, you linked, said it is more reliable. Thank you!